# rails 4 - param is missing or the value is empty: projecttype

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

A newby to rails (I am building an app to learn rails) and run in to an issue I can't find a solution to (while following the getting started guide). I have studied the guides and similar questions

This is my code:

```
    class ProjecttypesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @projecttypes = Projecttype.all
    end

    def show
        @projecttype = Projecttype.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
    end

    def create
        @projecttype = Projecttype.new(projecttype_params)
        @projecttype.save
        redirect_to @projecttype
    end

    private
        def projecttype_params
            params.require(:projecttype).permit(:name, :image, :url)
        end
end
```

The form:

```
    <%= form_for :projecttypes, url: projecttypes_path do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label 'Project type' %>
        <%= f.text_field :projecttype %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.label :image %>
        <%= f.file_field :image %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.label :url %>
        <%= f.url_field :url %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Perhaps important... when I use this...

```
def create
    render plain: params[:projecttype].inspect
end
```

It returns 'nil'.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What about your form, can you paste that

Comment: added the form. Tx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your

controller file

```
def new
  @projecttype = Projecttype.new
end
```

and then in your form
`<%= form_for @projecttype do |f| %>`

Answer (score 3):

Your code should be like this

```
def new
   @projecttype = Projecttype.new
end

def create
    @projecttype = Projecttype.create(projecttype_params)
    redirect_to @projecttype
end
```

and use this for form

```
<%= form_for @projecttype do |f| %>
```

Comment: I think you meant: `<%= form_for @projecttype do |f| %>`

Comment: yes.check this link for properly understanding about form in rails
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-model-objects